# How to update table row with data from an array using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to update table rows from an array. The assignment requirement is that the table has to be pre-existing with no data, so I'm not allowed to append row data - I need to replace the data in the cells.

HTML table

```
<table id="test">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Jan</th>
      <th>Feb</th>
      <th>Mar</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Wind Speed</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Solar Radiation</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

jQuery code

```
var arr = [[13,14,15],[3,4,5]];

$.each(arr, function(rowIndex, r){
  $.each(r, function(colIndex, c){ 
    $("td").text(c);
  });
});
```

It should output data from the array in the cells, but it's only outputting 5 in the empty cells, which is the last value in the last array.
I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but I can't figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
$("#test tbody tr:eq(" + rowIndex + ") td:eq(" + colIndex + ")").text(c);
```

Problem is that when you use `$("td").text(c);` you set each `td` with the same value.

**Working demo**

```js
var arr = [
  [13, 14, 15],
  [3, 4, 5]
];

$.each(arr, function(rowIndex, r) {
  $.each(r, function(colIndex, c) {
    $("#test tbody tr:eq(" + rowIndex + ") td:eq(" + colIndex + ")").text(c);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="test">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Jan</th>
      <th>Feb</th>
      <th>Mar</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Wind Speed</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Solar Radiation</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @JasonCollier No problem happy to help